# Query using Dapper in C# & MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, dapper

I'm new to C# and I'm making a small software to practice.

I've built a query to get the last Dispatch_ID number(which is not Auto-increment). The code i'm using goes something like this:

```
public string GetLastDispatchNum()
    {
        using (IDbConnection connection = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(Helper.CnnVal("FineCreteDB")))
        {
            var output=connection.Query("SELECT `Dispatch_ID` FROM `DispatchData` ORDER BY `Dispatch_ID` DESC LIMIT 1").Select(x=>x.Dispatch_ID).ElementAt(0);
            return output;
        }
    }
```

Although this does get my job done, I feel I'm not using dapper properly here, and this can be much neater. The query "SELECT `Dispatch_ID` FROM `DispatchData` ORDER BY `Dispatch_ID` DESC LIMIT 1" itself returns just one value & one column. Therefore using .Select(x=>x.Dispatch_ID) & .ElementAt(0) seems a bit repetitive.

Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it adds much compared to the other answers, but I prefer `QuerySingle` in cases where I expect a single value. It throws an exception if there isn't exactly one item in the result set.

```cs
public int GetLastDispatchNum()
{
    using (IDbConnection connection = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(Helper.CnnVal("FineCreteDB")))
    {
        int output=connection.QuerySingle<int>("SELECT `Dispatch_ID` FROM `DispatchData` ORDER BY `Dispatch_ID` DESC LIMIT 1").Select(x=>x.Dispatch_ID).ElementAt(0);
        return output;
    }
}
```

It ensures two things:

- A default value (maybe null) won't cause problems at a later stage.
- An inconsistency in my database or my database model won't go unnoticed.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use this instead:

```
var output=connection.Query<int>("SELECT `Dispatch_ID` FROM `DispatchData` ORDER BY `Dispatch_ID` DESC LIMIT 1").FirstOrDefault();
```

Can't say it is technically any better/faster, but seems cleaner to me.

Comment: Thank you. I understand maybe its not faster or better, but I just didn't want to get into the habit of programming "incorrectly".

Answer (score 0):

To update the Dapper query so you don't have to use .ElementAt(0), you can simply write out the Dapper code like:

```
// Assuming that Dispatch_ID is an int
var output = connection.QueryFirst<int>("SELECT `Dispatch_ID` FROM `DispatchData` ORDER BY `Dispatch_ID` DESC LIMIT 1");
```

Also if you want to use the generic in Dapper functions I would recommend that you use something that matches what you are retrieving, hence why I changed it from `<DispatchData>` to `<int>`.

Comment: Thanks, this is much cleaner. And clears up a few things about dapper for me.

Comment: When you're just querying for a single scalar value (the first column of the first row of a result set), you can also use `ExecuteScalar<int>`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code to connect the Exsiting DataBase:

```
using (var connection = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user=root;password=YOURPASSWORD;database=DapperDemoDb;"))
{
    connection.Open();

    var students = connection.Query<Student>("SELECT * FROM student;").ToList();

    foreach (var student in students)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"ID: {student.Id}, Name: {student.Name}, Email: {student.Email}");
    }
}
```